# "<Class> is declared but its value never read" and "Cannot find name <Class>" at same time

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-router

I am using React and Typescript and `react-router` - I want to use `RouteComponentProps` to bind `this.props.history` automatically. This is my code:

```
import * as React from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import {
    RouteComponentProps,
    withRouter,
} from "react-router-native";
import Example from "../../screens/Example";

interface Props {}

interface State {}

class ExampleContainer extends React.Component<RouteComponentProps & Props, State> {

    isValid(value): void {
      if (value!=="") {
        this.props.history.push('/tasks')
      }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Example callback={(value: string) => this.isValid(value)}  />
        );
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (_) => ({});
const mapStateToProps = (_) => ({});
export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ExampleContainer));
```

However, I get a weird compiler error telling me that `RouteComponentProps` is never used, but **at the same time** it is not defined. Here the exact error message:

```
src/containers/ExampleContainer/index.tsx:4:2 - error TS6133: 'RouteComponentProps' is declared but its value is never read.

4  RouteComponentProps,
   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

src/containers/ExampleContainer/index.tsx:13:48 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'RouteComponentProps'.

13 class ExampleContainer extends React.Component<RouteComponentProps & Props, State> {
                                                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

How do I bind `react-router` props correctly? I believe I should at least get a `TypeError` of some sort if I am doing it wrong, but I can not comprehend this error...
I appreciate any help pointing me to the source of the error. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by changing

```
import {
    RouteComponentProps,
    withRouter,
} from "react-router-native";
```

To

```
import { withRouter } from "react-router-native";
import { RouteComponentProps }  from "react-router";
```

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this by adding ignore pattern to `.eslintrc` :

```js
"no-unused-vars": [1, {
  "args": "none",
  "varsIgnorePattern": "RouteComponentProps"
}],
```